# How to sum rows and then subtract them grouped by?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE test
    (`id` int, `type` int, `summ` int)
;

INSERT INTO test
    (`id`, `type`, `summ`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 100),
    (2, 1, 200),
    (3, 2, 250),
    (4, 2, 20),
    (5, 3, 10)
;
```

sql:

```
SELECT
  type, SUM(summ) as total
FROM
  test
GROUP BY
  type
```

Result is 3 rows grouped by `type` and summed values of `total`: 1 - 300, 2 - 270, 3 - 10.

**Q:** How to subtract final `total` results from type `1` to all others (`2` and `3`)? Result will be: 300 - 270 - 10 = 20.
So, I need to get `20` as a result.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4df28/1

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4df28/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `SUM` and `CASE`:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN type = 1 THEN summ ELSE -summ END) as total
FROM test
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4df28/5/0)**</kbd>

Records with `type = 1` will be unchanged and rest will be negated.